# How to add css for the selected row in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a html grid in a div. This grid has one editable column, the query is when we do editing on it with correct data there is red image is showing which should not be shown.

for this have created a css class:

```
#divPromotionExceptions .errorRemove {    
    background-image:none;
}
```

And in js file put below code on

```
saveClick() {
     if (success) {
        $('.x-grid3-dirty-cell').addClass('errorRemove');
    }
    else {
        if ($('.x-grid3-dirty-cell').hasClass('errorRemove')) {
            $('.x-grid3-dirty-cell').removeClass('errorRemove');
        }
    }
```

Query is my code remove and add the image for all the rows together while i need to apply row wise.

note: if grid has three rows then it has three divs and corresponding tables.
Below  is the html grid:

```
       grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
       store: promotionExceptionStore,
       width: ($$('divPromotionExceptions').width() - 5),
       stripeRows: true,
       height: 225,
    region: 'center',
    margins: '0 5 5 5',
    plugins: [editor],
    columnLines: true,
    columns: [
    new Ext.grid.RowNumberer(),
     {
         id: 'Action',
         dataIndex: 'Action',
         header: 'Actions',
         width: 100,
         sortable: false,
         readOnly: true,
         renderer: LinkRenderer,
         tooltip: 'Actions'
         },
        {
         id: 'OfficeNumber',
        dataIndex: 'OfficeNumber',
        header: 'Office',
        width: 50,
        sortable: true,
        tooltip: 'Branch Number'
    },
     {
         id: 'AccountNumber',
         dataIndex: 'AccountNumber',
         header: 'Account',
         width: 60,
         sortable: true,
         tooltip: 'Account Number'
     },
        {
          id: 'FANumber',
          dataIndex: 'FANumber',
          header: 'FA',
          width: 50,
         sortable: true,
         tooltip: 'FA Number'
     },
    {
        id: 'Name',
        header: 'Client Name',
        dataIndex: 'Name',
        width: 220,
        sortable: true,
        tooltip: 'Name'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
        header: 'Exception Amount($)',
        dataIndex: 'Amount',
        width: 150,
        sortable: true,
        tooltip: 'Exception Amount($)',
        format: '0,000',

        editor: {
            allowBlank: false,
            //                maxLength: 13,
            minValue: 1,
            autoCreate: { tag: 'input', type: 'text', size: '20', autocomplete: 'off', maxlength: 13 },
            vtype: 'currencycheck',
            validationDelay: 100,
            listeners: {
                'render': function(c) {
                    var currentId = c.getEl().id;
                    $$(currentId).attr('maxlength', '13');
                    //$$(currentId).bind("cut copy paste", function(e) {    e.preventDefault(); });
                    $$(currentId).preventString();  //SKB Change
                    $$(currentId).maskMoney({ symbol: "", precision: 0 });
                },
                'focus': function(c) {
                    var currentId = c.getEl().id;
                    if ($$(currentId).val() != '') {
                        $$(currentId).format({ format: "#,###", locale: "us" });
                    }
                },
                'blur': function(c) {

                    var currentId = c.getEl().id;
                    var currentValue = $$(currentId).val();
                    currentValue = currentValue.replace(/,/g, '');
                    $$(currentId).val(currentValue);
                    //$$(currentId).unmaskMoney();

                },
                'beforestaterestore': function(c, d) {
                }
             }
          }
       },
    {
        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
        id: 'AmountUsed',
        header: 'Exception Amount Used($)',
        dataIndex: 'AmountUsed',
        width: 180,
        sortable: true,
        format: '0,000',
        tooltip: 'Exception Amount Used($)'

       },
       {
        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
        id: 'HHAssets',
        dataIndex: 'HHAssets',
        header: 'HHAssets ($)',
        width: 180,
        sortable: true,
        format: '0,000',
        tooltip: 'House Holding Assets($)'
      },
      {
        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
        id: 'Trailing12MonthsRevenue',
        dataIndex: 'Trailing12MonthsRevenue',
        header: 'Trailing 12 Months Revenue($)',
        width: 150,
        sortable: true,
        format: '0,000',
        tooltip: 'Account Revenue($)'
       },
       {
        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
        id: 'CommissionRevenue',
        dataIndex: 'CommissionRevenue',
        header: 'Commission Revenue($)',
        width: 150,
        sortable: true,
        format: '0,000',
        tooltip: 'HouseHold Revenue($)'
        },
        {
        header: 'KeyAccount',
        dataIndex: 'KeyAccount',
        width: 200,
        sortable: true,
        //hidden: true,
        //menuDisabled: true,
        tooltip: 'KeyAccount'
        }

        ]

       });
```

and save button:

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSave" runat="server" PostBackUrl="#"  OnClientClick="saveClick(); window.returnValue=false; return false;" >
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you scoping out your css with the "#divPromotionExceptions"? How about changing that to just ".errorRemove"?

Comment: #divPromotionExceptions is the main div and other child div and table do not have id. The td has .x-grid3-dirty-cell css class so first i removed the image by adding new css class .errorRemove and then add the image by removing this class. Thanks.

Comment: @Joakim: how can I get the row index/value of selected row.

Comment: You need to provide your HTML. Dont keep us guessing on that.. Also hasClass is not needed there, you can just call removeClass.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSave" runat="server" PostBackUrl="#"  OnClientClick="saveClick(this); window.returnValue=false; return false;" >
```

Pass `this` to the in the click handler `saveClick(this)`.

Assuming the button is inside the `td` and `td` is inside `tr`. As you want to change the class of `row`.

Inside your saveClick use

```
saveClick(target) {
     var $activeTr = $(target).closest('tr');
     if (success) {
        $activeTr.addClass('errorRemove');
    }
    else {
        if ($activeTr.hasClass('errorRemove')) {
            $activeTr.removeClass('errorRemove');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried with your code now,but target is not able to add the css class, I tried with same logic by using this object but not get success. that is why i added the class with other css class.

Comment: No Luck!!! I am using external css http://toolkits.ms.com/webaurora/ria/ext/3.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css and cause of this it is not able to add errorRemove class to particular row (tr). Can we have any approach to find .x-grid3-dirty-cell class for particular row and then add errorRemove  class to it. .x-grid3-dirty-cell  class is defined in above external css.

Comment: `$('.x-grid3-dirty-cell').addClass('errorRemove')` This will find the dirty cell and adds `errorRemove` class to that. Just update the `$activeTr` with  `$('.x-grid3-dirty-cell')` in above code it will work :)

Comment: I used the same to my code. but this is changing the image for all rows not for particular row which is my query. See my query at beginning. :)